# How to extract multiple text outside tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, text, beautifulsoup, extract

I want to scrape a web page (German complaint website) using BeautifulSoup. Here is a good example (https://de.reclabox.com/beschwerde/44870-deutsche-bahn-berlin-erstattungsbetrag-sparpreisticket)

```html
<div id="comments" class="kt">
    <a name="comments"></a>
    <span class="bb">Kommentare und Trackbacks (7)</span>
    <br><br><br>
      <a id="comment100264" name="comment100264"></a>
      <div class="data">
        19.12.2011 | 11:04
      </div>
        von Tom K.
      <!--
      -->
          | <a class="flinko" href="/users/login?functionality_required=1">Regelverstoß melden</a>
      <div class="linea"></div>
          TEXT I AM INTEREST IN<br><br>MORE TEXT I AM INTEREST IN<br><br>MORETEXT I AM INTEREST IN
      
      <br><br>
      <a id="comment100265" name="comment100265"></a>
      <div class="data">
        19.12.2011 | 11:11
      </div>
        von Tom K.
      <!--
      -->
          | <a class="flinko" href="/users/login?functionality_required=1">Regelverstoß melden</a>
      <div class="linea"></div>
          TEXT I AM INTEREST IN<br><br>MORE TEXT I AM INTEREST IN
            
      <br><br>
      <a id="comment101223" name="comment101223"></a>
        <div class="commentbox comment-not-yet-solved">
      <div class="data">
        25.12.2011 | 10:14
      </div>
        von ReclaBoxler-4134668
      <!--
      --><img alt="noch nicht gelöste Beschwerde" src="https://a1.reclabox.com/assets/live_tracking/not_yet_solve-dbf4769c625b73b23618047471c72fa45bacfeb1cf9058655c4d75aecd6e0277.png" title="noch nicht gelöste Beschwerde">
          | <a class="flinko" href="/users/login?functionality_required=1">Regelverstoß melden</a>
      <div class="linea"></div>
          TEXT I AM NOT INTERESTED IN <br><br>TEXT I AM NOT INTERESTED IN 
      
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <a id="comment101237" name="comment101237"></a>
      <div class="data">
        25.12.2011 | 11:01
      </div>
        von ReclaBoxler-3315297
      <!--
      -->
          | <a class="flinko" href="/users/login?functionality_required=1">Regelverstoß melden</a>
      <div class="linea"></div>
          TEXT I AM INTERESTED IN 
      
      
      <br><br>

etc...     
      
      <br><br>
  <br><br>
</div>
```

I was able to scrape most of the content I want (thanks to a lot of Q&A's I read here:-)) except for the comments (`<div id="comments" class="kt">`) which are not in a `class ="commentbox"` (I got the commentboxes already with another command). The comments outside the comment boxes seem to be not in a normal tag, that's why I just did not manage to get them via `"soup.find(_all)"`. I'd like to scrape these comments as well as information about the person posting the comment ("von") as well as the date and time (`<div class="data">`).

It would be absolutely fantastic if someone knows how to solve this one. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The common task to extract all texts from a page as follows

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = """xxxxxxxx""" // url name
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "html.parser")
print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! I tried your suggestion: 

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = "https://de.reclabox.com/beschwerde/44870"
page = urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup.get_text())

Unfortunately, I ended up with text outside of the complaint, like imprint etc.